# Find the volume under the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I need to find the volume of this surface:
$$z = x^2+y^2$$
On the domain limited by:
$$y = x^2$$
$$y = 1$$
$$z=0$$
It appears to me that this is the proper way to integrate this:
$$\int_{x =-1}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y= x^2}(x^2+y^2)dydx$$
However, when I do this I get the result $V = 52/105$ and the correct answer is supposed to be $V= \frac{88}{105}$. Did I use the wrong limits for integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you used the wrong limits. It should have been:$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^1x^2+y^2\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$You will get $\frac{88}{105}$ indeed.

Comment: I spent three hours looking at this integral and my mistake was so stupid. . Poor 3 hours:(